# Order a resultset by a specific requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

I use SQL-Server 2008 and have this problem, which is explained best by an example:

Let's say I have this number 3776. I want to order my resulting list as following:

```
3775
3777
3774
3778
3773
3779
...
```

In other words based on 3776 as close a possible in both directions, plus AND minus.

E.g. this would give me only the positive order:

```
where FIELDNAME > 3776
order by FIELDNAME asc
```

How can I get the required result?

Comment: When two numbers are same as close to 3776, is there some criteria about which one must be shown first? The greater one or the smaller one?

Answer (score 1):

You could order your query by the absolute difference between 3776 and the field's value:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY ABS(3776 - fieldname)
```

Comment: @Murenik should not you add    , fieldname    in your order clause?

Comment: @etsa that would prioritize values smaller than `3776` over values larger than it. You could, but it doesn't seem to be what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: @Murenik, as far as I can see it's what he asked... (and in theory you should add WHERE <>3776 too...  :-)

Comment: @etsa the requirement is "n other words based on 3776 as close a possible in both directions, plus AND minus." OP gave `order by FIELDNAME` as his current attempt that doesn't produce the right value

Answer (score 0):

```
with t(col) as (
    select 3775 union all 
    select 3777  union all 
    select 3774  union all 
    select 3778  union all 
    select 3773  union all 
    select 3779
    )
 select *  from t
 order by abs(col - 3776), col
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startnum int = 1;
DECLARE @endnum int = 21;
DECLARE @point int = 11;


WITH seq AS 
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM seq WHERE num + 1 <= @endnum
),
cte AS
(
    SELECT num, abs(@point - num) [shift]
        FROM seq 
)
SELECT num
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY [shift], num;
```

Output:

```
num
-----------
11
10
12
9
13
8
14
7
15
6
16
5
17
4
18
3
19
2
20
1
21
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this.  I think the order by clause is important to obtain the same sequence for all records (you can decide to use X ASC  or X DESC ):

```
WITH Y AS (SELECT 3775 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 3776 UNION ALL SELECT 3774 
           UNION ALL SELECT 3773 UNION ALL SELECT 3778 UNION ALL SELECT 3779 
           UNION ALL SELECT 3777)
SELECT X
FROM Y 
WHERE X<>3776
ORDER BY ABS(3776-X), X ASC;
```

Output:

```
3775
3777
3774
3778
3773
3779
```

If you use

```
WITH Y AS (SELECT 3775 AS X UNION ALL SELECT 3776 UNION ALL SELECT 3774 
           UNION ALL SELECT 3773 UNION ALL SELECT 3778 UNION ALL SELECT 3779 
           UNION ALL SELECT 3777)
SELECT X
FROM Y 
WHERE X<>3776
ORDER BY ABS(3776-X)
```

you can obtain following.  It's important to remember that if you don't specify an order by clause, the order of the record is not deterministic.  So if you just specify ORDER BY ABS(3776-X) you can't be sure if greater or smaller number (having same ABS difference with starting number) appear first.

```
3775
3777
3774
3778
3779
3773
```